# Search Django Model Returns All Instead Of Filter

Tags: django

I am trying to search my Django model but, cannot return the filter result. I am getting all items in the model.

```
class singleview(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    
    authentication_classes = []

    permission_classes = []
    search_fields = ['name']
    filter_backends= (filters.SearchFilter,)
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class =ProductSerializer
```

The Url is:

> url(r'^api/dualsearch/$', views.singleview.as_view()),

When searching:

> http://localhost:8000/api/singleview/?name=n

I return all items. Could you please help return the results in the filter?

Comment: It's `search_fields`.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue. Searching still shows all items instead of the needed results

Answer (score 0):

According the DRF documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter):

> By default, the search parameter is named 'search', but this may be
> overridden with the SEARCH_PARAM setting.

You must use the `search` parameter instead of `name`:

`http://localhost:8000/api/singleview/?search=n`

... and correct the `search_field` to `search_fields` property as @WillemVanOnsem says.

**EDIT**

I add a full working example:

```py
from rest_framework import generics, routers, serializers, viewsets, filters

class SingleView(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []

    permission_classes = []
    search_fields = ['name']
    filter_backends= (filters.SearchFilter,)
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', SingleView)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    # ...
]
```

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/?search=n
```

Comment: I have updated the search field. Name is one of the attributes within the model. Using "search" returned error asking for the corresponding attribute that is being searched for.

Comment: @DoingThingsOccasionally, I add a real world probed example.